# BitmapDrawable() method deprecated

Tags: android, bitmap, background

What can I use in replace of BitmapDrawable(), which is deprecated. I have the following code. I just want to clear the background of this view.

```
popupMessage = new PopupWindow(view, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupMessage.setContentView(view);

            // Clear the default translucent background
            popupMessage.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popupMessage.setBackgroundDrawable(null)` will clear the background.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29):

> Change the background drawable for this popup window. The background
>   can be set to null.